# Basic logic: $A\to C$ and $B\to C$ is equivalent to $A\lor B\to C$?

Tags: logic

Consider the two results: "if A holds, then C", "if B holds, then C".
From these, is it correct to write a theorem that says "if A or B hold, then C"?

Comment: Indeed they are equivalent. See [this proof tree](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((A→C)∧(B→C))↔((A∨B)→C)).

Comment: @player3236 thank you.  I didn't know about such thing as  a "proof generator".

Comment: Just a small reminder that this "tree proof generator" do not give the shortest possible proof via natural deduction. I see a proof of your equivalence within 5 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent, as Player says.  But beware.  Some students are confused into thinking (falsely) that
$$
(\forall x)A(x) \rightarrow C \quad\wedge\quad (\forall x) B(x) \rightarrow C 
$$
is equivalent to
$$
(\forall x)(A(x) \vee B(x)) \rightarrow C 
$$

Comment: Yes, the latter doesn't imply the former.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I’m wrong here but that proof tree looks massively convoluted, and the solution is straightforward. I’ll write my answer like pseudocode.

Suppose (A or B) is true.

$\quad$ If A is true then C is true.

$\quad$ Else B is true, so C is true.

In either case, C is true.